# AngularJS Template not rendering in safari?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

Ok, so I was asked by a colleague to take a look at a module they had written to show an instagram feed of their account on the website. The module works fine in Chrome, IE, Firefox, but NOT in safari. I took a look at the template, everything looks fine. I literally have no idea what it would be.

The code pulling the images from instagram is

```
angular.module("inkedRaskal", [])
    // .filter('fromTo', function() {
    //     return function(input, from, total, lessThan) {
    //         from = parseInt(from);
    //         total = parseInt(total);
    //         for (var i = from; i < from + total && i < lessThan; i++) {
    //             input.push(i);
    //         }
    //         return input;
    //     }
    // })
    .factory('instagram', ['$http',
        function($http) {
            return {
                fetchPopular: function(callback) {

                    var endPoint = "APIKEYFORUSER"; // can guarantee this is correct

                    $http.jsonp(endPoint).success(function(response) {
                        callback(response.data);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    ])
    .controller("instagramController", function($scope, $interval, instagram) {
      $scope.pics = [];
      $scope.have = [];
      $scope.orderBy = "-likes.count";
      $scope.getMore = function() {

        instagram.fetchPopular(function(data) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
              if (typeof $scope.have[data[i].id]==="undefined") {
                $scope.pics.push(data[i]) ;
                $scope.have[data[i].id] = "1";
              }
            }
        });
      };
      $scope.getMore();

        // $scope.tags = [
        //     'Bootstrap', 'AngularJS', 'Instagram', 'Factory'
        // ]
    });
```

And the template code (HTML) looks like this:

```
<div class="insta-container" ng-controller="instagramController">

            <div ng-repeat="p in pics | limitTo: 7" class="col-sm-2 item-{{ $index }} instablocks"  ng-class="{first: $first, last:$last}">
                <a class="inst-link" href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank">
                    <img ng-src="{{p.images.standard_resolution.url}}" class="img-responsive" title="{{p.caption.text}}">
                </a>     
            </div>

        </div>
```

The page that this is happening on is fedesignandconsulting.com (towards the bottom). For reference, I am printing the response from Instagram to the console for anyone who feels like taking a look at this for me. Spent a lot of time googling, found nothing related to this specifically. Thanks ahead!

Comment: I am not seeing anything in the console, however, I do see the API call is successful in both chrome and safari. It is odd that you are actually seeing `{{p.caption.text}}` in safari and there are no errors in the console. Usually when you see that there is an error. Can you output `$scope.pics` to the console? Another thing to note, they should be using `ng-href` not `href`